# using glib library in c program

Tags: c, linux, glib

I want to use hash tables in my c program.

I code:

```
...
#include <glib.h>

void main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  GHashTable *g_hash_table;
  ...  
  g_hash_table = g_hash_table_new(g_int_hash, g_int_equal);
...
}
```

Then I compile:

```
$ gcc -I/usr/include/glib-2.0
-I/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include
-lglib-2.0 -o test test.c
```

or the same command:

```
$ gcc `pkg-config --cflags --libs glib-2.0` -o test test.c
```

but anyway the result is:

```
test.c: underfined reference to `g_int_equal`
test.c: underfined reference to `g_int_hash` 
test.c: underfined reference to `g_hash_table_new`
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

**Why I cant compile my program? I do wrong include of glib library?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to specify libraries in the command line *after* the source and object files that use them:

```
gcc test.c `pkg-config --cflags --libs glib-2.0` -o test
```

Answer (score 1):

From [this pdf](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/tutorials/l-glib/l-glib-pdf.pdf) at IBM developper works, it's better to use the pkg-config if you have a standard install of `glib` with this command :

```
$ gcc `pkg-config --cflags --libs glib-2.0` -o ex-compile ex-compile.c
```

Your include look right and the way you are using it to. Not sure the `'` will change anything but you might want to check the PDF, it contains a lot of examples and explainations.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I did that as in the pdf, but anyway I cant compile this.

Comment: The apostrophes should be backticks.